Django send mail works in localhost but not on server
I recently started to learn Django and I wrote a code to send an email in contact us page and it works fine in my localhost but when I uploaded it onto server it gave this error:
SMTPServerDisconnected at /contact
Connection unexpectedly closed

this is my settings.py code:
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app passwords'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'


and this is my views.py
send_mail('title', 'message', userEmail, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False,)

I talked to the support group of my host server to check the ports but they said it was okay so I don't know if I'm missing something or not.

Here are a few suggestions to diagnose the issue:

Port 587 might be blocked or TLS might not be working. You can also test SSL.

Test port 465 instead of 587, both with TLS and SSL.

To check for blocking, use tools like telnet, netcat, or openssl to verify the port's accessibility.


Configure TLS or SSL in your settings.py using the variables EMAIL_USE_SSL=True or EMAIL_USE_TLS=True.

thank you but I ended up changing the host
